# FontStyle: 'italic' not working in IOS React native

Tags: react-native

This is the react native simpler code of turning text into italic, however its working fine in the android device but not working in IOS for some reason.
my react native version : 0.71.4

...
`<Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.textStyle}> Featured In </Text>`
...

`textStyle: { ... marginLeft: -30, fontStyle: 'italic', },`

[Android Output of text with style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdT1.png)
[IOS Output of text with no style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxvIk.png)

I've tried searching for this problem but did not find anything over stack-overflow, I hope i get the answer as quick as possible, thanks

Comment: What font family are you using on this?

Comment: None, Im using react native Default fontStyle and its not providing satisfactory output in IOS only.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild the app:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
npm run ios
```